# How to disable eslint 'no-undef' for a specific package import?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm working with a framework ('hardhat') that automatically requires a package ('ethers') but eslint keeps calling it out as undefined. Requiring 'ethers' is not a solution because it just breaks everything; but from what I understand, a way to add exceptions to the entire document is to place overrides in a comment block above the entire thing.

```
 /*
    eslint-disable jest/valid-expect
 */ 
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { txHist } = require("../scripts/utils.js");

describe("DStor", () => {
    let DStor;
    let deployer, user1, user2, user3, users; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

    beforeEach(async () => {
        // Get ContractFactory and Signers
        const DStorFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("DStor"); // 'ethers' is highlighted with no-undef
...
```

I suspect the solution is to add another eslint-disable rule, but I don't know how to target the 'ethers' package with it. Anyone have any solutions?

Update: fixed by adding `const { ethers } = require("hardhat");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [ESLint globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals). Basically, you can declare a global value `ethers` in your ESLint configuration, and that will be treated as defined in all linted files.

For ESLint >= 7, if your configuration file is .eslintrc, add an entry like:

```json
{
    "globals": {
        "ethers": "readonly"
    }
}
```

For ESLint < 7, use `"ethers": false` instead.